# protect the text box to not take that blank value after clearing the previous value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to protect a text box to not accept any values except numbers. Which I achieved with the following code

```
function allowOnlyNumber(evt) { 
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode 
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) 
        return false; 
    return true;  
}
```

The issue is: when I am entering a number to the text box and saving by clicking UPDATE button linked to it its getting saved which the expected. but Second time when I select the number from that text box and clear it through Delete or Backspace keys from keyboard and clicking on UPDATE button linked to it, the blank value getting updated.

How can I protect the text box to not take that blank value? It should retain the previous valid value.

Comment: check its not equal to `""`

Comment: Welcome to SO. if you want to get an answer specific to your code including the submit, please post the whole code. otherwise we can only give you general answers.

Comment: Does the textbox having any values after initial load? Or is it blank at initial?

Comment: @Maibub Patil what else you expect, You are clicking Update button.You need to apply required field validation on your textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code piece on OnLoad function

```
var preVal = $("#txt").val();
$("#txt").change(function()
    {
        if($(this).val().trim() == '')
        {
            $(this).val(preVal);
        }
        preVal = $("#txt").val();
    }
);
```

The working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t24Eg/146/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.trim()` jQuery method to prevent the blank value to get submitted.

Try with this like:

```
var elem = $('yourelemId').val(); // get the specific value
if($.trim(elem) === ""){ // use trim to remove any whitespace
   alert('Your alert msg here');
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this.. Short Code not accepting numbers at all.

```
$("#txt").keyup(function() { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\.]/g,'');
});
```

working here  http://jsfiddle.net/kz573/1/